# What is the "best" method for saving games in XNA?

Tags: encryption, xna, save

I have been struggling with finding a good method for storing save game data in XNA.

What would be a good method to go about saving game information that is encrypted and not easily readable/editable by others?

Comment: you can save it as txt file, or xml... depend on you. and for encryption you can use md5 or des allready build into visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually like Json but because you don't want it readable, you should use a binary serializer. Note that with binary serialization, new saves are not reverse compatible with older saves because the serialization and deserialization process follow a strict structure and is invalidated as soon as changes are made to it. You can then encrypt your binary save file using Rijndael or something like that.